# Get Weekly Hours and Monthly Hours From a Task Table Based on Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a task table as below

| employee_id | task | date | hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01-01-2023 | 4 |
| 1 | B | 01-01-2023 | 4 |
| 1 | A | 02-01-2023 | 4 |
| 1 | B | 02-01-2023 | 4 |
| 1 | A | 03-01-2023 | 8 |
| 1 | B | 03-01-2023 | 8 |
| 1 | A | 04-01-2023 | 8 |
| 1 | B | 05-01-2023 | 8 |
| 1 | A | 06-01-2023 | 8 |
| 1 | B | 07-01-2023 | 8 |

I would like to get the weekly and monthly total work hours for each task based on the date for each employee.

I am trying to write a mysql query for calculating the weekly and monthly hours from the task table

My desired output is

| employee_id | task | week1_hours | week2_hours | week3_hours | week4_hours | week5_hours | monthly_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 4 | 28 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 32 |
| 1 | B | 4 | 28 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 32 |

Based on the month and task all the weekly hours should be calculated, both monthly and weekly hours

In the result, I am getting a empty result set, in my table for some days A task will present and in some days B task will present, it is not necessary that both A and B task will present for all the days, Kindly help me in solving this SQL query

Here is my SQL CTC Query:

```
WITH weekly_hours_1 AS (
  SELECT 
    employee_id, 
    task, 
    SUM(hours) AS week1_hours 
  FROM 
    employee_id 
  WHERE 
    DATE BETWEEN '2023-01-01' 
    AND '2023-01-01' 
  GROUP BY 
    task
), 
weekly_hours_2 AS (
  SELECT 
    employee_id, 
    task, 
    SUM(hours) AS week2_hours 
  FROM 
    employee_id 
  WHERE 
    DATE BETWEEN '2023-01-02' 
    AND '2023-01-08' 
  GROUP BY 
    task
), 
weekly_hours_3 AS (
  SELECT 
    employee_id, 
    task, 
    SUM(hours) AS week3_hours 
  FROM 
    employee_id 
  WHERE 
    DATE BETWEEN '2023-01-09' 
    AND '2023-01-15' 
  GROUP BY 
    task
), 
weekly_hours_4 AS (
  SELECT 
    employee_id, 
    task, 
    SUM(hours) AS week4_hours 
  FROM 
    employee_id 
  WHERE 
    DATE BETWEEN '2023-01-16' 
    AND '2023-01-22' 
  GROUP BY 
    task
), 
weekly_hours_5 AS (
  SELECT 
    employee_id, 
    task, 
    SUM(hours) AS week5_hours 
  FROM 
    employee_id 
  WHERE 
    DATE BETWEEN '2023-01-23' 
    AND '2023-01-29' 
  GROUP BY 
    task
), 
monthly_hours AS (
  SELECT 
    employee_id, 
    task, 
    SUM(hours) AS monthly_hours 
  FROM 
    employee_id 
  WHERE 
    DATE BETWEEN '2022-12-22' 
    AND '2022-12-24' 
  GROUP BY 
    task
) 
SELECT 
  monthly_hours.employee_id, 
  monthly_hours.task, 
  monthly_hours.m_hours, 
  weekly_hours_1.w_hours, 
  weekly_hours_2.w_hours, 
  weekly_hours_3.w_hours, 
  weekly_hours_4.w_hours, 
  weekly_hours_5.w_hours 
FROM 
  monthly_hours 
  JOIN weekly_hours_1 ON weekly_hours_1.employee_id = monthly_hours.employee_id 
  AND monthly_hours.task = weekly_hours_1.task 
  JOIN weekly_hours_2 ON weekly_hours_2.employee_id = monthly_hours.employee_id 
  AND monthly_hours.task = weekly_hours_2.task 
  JOIN weekly_hours_3 ON weekly_hours_3.employee_id = monthly_hours.employee_id 
  AND monthly_hours.task = weekly_hours_3.task 
  JOIN weekly_hours_4 ON weekly_hours_4.employee_id = monthly_hours.employee_id 
  AND monthly_hours.task = weekly_hours_4.task 
  JOIN weekly_hours_5 ON weekly_hours_5.employee_id = monthly_hours.employee_id 
  AND monthly_hours.task = weekly_hours_5.task 
WHERE 
  weekly_hours_1.employee_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
GROUP BY 
  monthly_hours.task_id
```

Comment: Can you add how does the sample value in week1_hours and week2_hours come to be whats mentioned when checked from sample data, i.e., the logic behind them.

Comment: The logic of week1hours, week2hours is the sum of hours for each task for each week in the Jan Month. The week duration can be the normal calendar dates Eg: Jan 2023 week 2 start date is 2nd Jan 2023 o 8th Jan 2023

Comment: Wouldn't be the 2nd week starting from 8th jan ?

Comment: Yes, If it start from sunday to saturday, it will start from 8th Jan 2023 to 14th Jan 2023

First week is from 1st Jan 2023 to 7th Jan 2023, this can be the right one